# Bitcoin code for PayPal

Tags: paypal

I am interested in one question, is it possible that someone protected the company's paypal account with bitcoin when making transactions

Comment: Hi Adriana, could you please elaborate your question? I do not understand what you mean with “someone protected the company's paypal account with bitcoin”.

Comment: a person uses paypal to pay for his services and when he wants to send money to someone, he asks for verification of the transfer in bitcoins. The account is supposedly protected from fraud that way. When, for example, bitcoin is paid to moonpay, he only asks for a code from the mail that arrives as confirmation that it was successful  buying bitcoins

Answer (score 2):

> is it possible that someone protected the company's paypal account with bitcoin when making transactions

No.

That sort of nonsense is typical of the approach used by confidence tricksters (con men) who are trying to confuse you and pressure you into unwittingly giving money to thieves.

Often they will send you some kind of fake money (that looks real but can later be cancelled) and ask you to pay them a small part back in real money (using a method that can't be cancelled). They end up with your money, you end up being chased by a bank for a debt. You can end up with a wrecked credit rating and a criminal investigation for money laundering etc.

See

- [Is it normal to be asked for an advance fee on a withdrawal?](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/q/103891/13866)
- [Sugar Daddy Bitcoin](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/q/99816/13866)